# How can I delete a user and all files associated with them using VB6 and CMD?

Tags: vb6, cmd

I am making a small programe in Visual Studio 2012 and am integrating a few CMD prompts.

I know how to execute CMD and delete a user from within VB6.
`Shell("net user """ + UserName.Text + """ /del")`

I need to basically find the user's directory and have it returned as a variable to execute `Shell("rd /s /q """ + DirectoryPath + """")`

Unless there's a way to delete files along with the user. So maybe there's an extension on `net user MyUsername /del`

I've looked around on Google and come up short so any help would be great
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The VB6 Shell() function does not invoke CMD.EXE unless you specifically run it.  VS 2012 does not contain VB6, so you may be confused about what you are using anyway.  This doesn't really seem to be a programming question at all, but an admin issue for ServerFault or somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe look at http://serverfault.com/questions/450389/how-to-delete-domain-user-profile-from-a-computer

Comment: Shell() does run CMD; I've used it to create a user and give them a password and a few other options and it all works fine

Comment: It may seem to "work fine" but clearly you don't know what's going on.  Scary.

Comment: So is there a way to do it using CMD alone?

Comment: No, but you aren't *using* "CMD" at all.  If you want it you have to provide it on the command line you pass.  If you don't need it don't worry about it, it's usually just extra overhead anyway.  But in your case you might try using it and redirecting the output to a disk file.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to describe what Josh Mason wants is to put in to you in a different way

so using the command

net user %username% /profile:{Full Path}

sets the profile path , is there a way of getting the profile path that is already set , so maybe using something like outputting the path to a notepad file then getting that into VB

i know you can use

net user %username% >> C:\currecutuser.txt

that would put the path into a text put along with all the other info , is there a way of just selecting the path and getting it into Vb somehow

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you Should do it like that

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
' get desktop path for current user
        TextBox3.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop.ToString

'strips "\Desktop"
        Dim path As String = TextBox3.Text.Replace("\Desktop", "")
        TextBox3.Text = path
    End Sub
```

then you could do `Process.Start(Textbox3.Text)`
to get that path
or do you want to delete that folder?

New Type i hope it make that thing work ;)

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ' get desktop path for current user
    TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop.ToString
    'input for username to delete
    Dim usertodel As String = InputBox("Type Username:")
    'strips "\Desktop" & curr user name
    Dim user As String = System.Environment.UserName
    Dim path1 As String = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\" & user & "\Desktop", "") '= C:\Users\

    TextBox1.Text = path1 & "\" & usertodel '= C:\Users\ + input box for user 

End Sub
```

it worked for me :)

Comment: I want to delete the users folder so I think what you mentioned might actually work as it would return "C:\Users\Josh", "Josh" being the folder I want to delete

Comment: Sorry, just as I was typing it up, I realized that this would get the current user's file path, so I would maybe have to replace the current users name with what's in the textbox to be deleted. is tjere a way to get the current users name?

Comment: Thank you for your help but what if the user that's being deleted has there folder in a different directory to the current user's?

Comment: hmm wait so if i am user Aleš and you user Josh then you want to delete my profile?

Comment: ok look at bottom of my answer ;) script has been improved, and i am tired now, when i wake up i will look if you responded ;)

Comment: Sorry, I've just looked at it, It's 00:32 and I am also tired so I'll have a look later:) Thanks